# Invalid redirect_uri: http://localhost:5001/signin-oidc

Tags: identityserver4

I developed my IdentityServer using the netcoreapp1.1 framework, IdentityServer4 version 1.52, with a console client the connection works fine, but with an MVC client netcoreapp2.0, within the records shows me:

```
error: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator [0] Redirect_uri inválido: http://localhost:5001/signin-oidc --code omitted-- error: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint [0] Request validation error
```

I did the steps that are in [api acces hybrid](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html) but I still have the same problem, for the client that I am working in the [mvc-hybrid](https://github.com/%20IdentityServer%20repository%20/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Clients/src/MvcHybrid) for an asp.net core 2 application without success, something that stands out is that the AllowedRedirectUris parameter is empty.

```
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0] Invalid redirect_uri: http://localhost:5001/signin-oidc { "ClientId": "client-hugo", "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5001/signin-oidc", "AllowedRedirectUris": [], "SubjectId": "anonymous", "RequestedScopes": "", "Raw": { "client_id": "client-hugo", "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5001/signin-oidc", "response_type": "code id_token", "scope": "openid profile email api-alumnos offline_access", "response_mode": "form_post", "nonce": "636412201009966900.ZDNmYjdmZWMtNWNlMS00ZDQyLWIxMjMtNWIzYTM4M2FhZmRhMmMxZGE2ZDUtM2M0MS00ZThiLTk4M2ItNDk2NGQ5YmZlODFj", "state": "CfDJ8J0brcCMivFPtUfbYRpOjISliA92IArZsJS1dmagQ9jYdvpmVj2ABROstPNhJyCWx8q4SntL6PXRubMgGqeUfdqWF0mNRAYifGy8OuEPZSQT295vWVfyN5gGhuvB6jQ043D14yUPLwkhS29IYfMoiliLQGatygTVnGMVJ7Bo-aV7FJcpHit-9b3RHRyaHiE0tToZdP8NxJInJ4vthIlXw1rgLjOmSqPxeN9KDfLgWrpki7XoBLkmV2K7px_GWp0ebaitkxnXTzDPg82M-nRJWfYLAXJ1nGvoZLD3GIXqFV22hDm0wmygbmRaMKezwZmHY12qr2pwa1N22aifJTZFzPY", "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET", "x-client-ver": "2.1.4.0" } } fail: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0] Request validation failed
```

What do you recommend me to do?

Comment: I know that the way authentication works was changed in asp.net core 2.0. Since your client app is running 2.0, you might try looking at the [dev branch of the mvc-hybrid sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/dev/Clients/src/MvcHybrid/Startup.cs). It looks like that has been updated for 2.0. Your problem might be due to using 1.0 style authentication in a 2.0 app.

Comment: @Peter your link is broken

Answer (score 8):

If you are using identity server 4, check your ClientRedirectUris table, check if your client has permission to redirect to your url. if not add new entry.

following figure shows the table:

[image: ClientRedirectUris created by Identityserver4]

Comment: where could I see that if I'm using `InMemory` storing yet?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your mvc client is running on http://localhost:5001

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to change the url from http://localhost:5001/clientA to http://localhost:5001 in the hosting.json file. Otherwise I needed to use the UsePathBase middleware which mess up the redirect URL since it always adds the path to each incoming request.